# null byte injection not happening

Tags: php

This is my code

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
include "$file.html";
```

When I pass a URL like this:
`test.php?file=sample.php%00`, 
the file sample.php should be included because of the null byte injection. But instead I'm getting an error: 
`Failed opening 'sample.php' for inclusion`.

I have checked the file path and also tried giving it the absolute path.

I am using PHP version 5.3.8 on Windows. What is it that I am missing here?  Thanks

Comment: do a `var_dump($_GET['file'])` and make sure that the null-byte's not being rewritten to something else. If the injection was still happening, you should get just the sample.php with a string length of 10

Comment: So, you're telling us if you modify that script to hardcode it, you can include `sample.php`?

Comment: This is the output of var_dump : string(11) "sample.php"

Comment: This is the output of var_dump : string(11) "sample.php". Marc B said the string length should be 10. what is my null byte getting rewritten to? printing $file[10] returns an empty string

Comment: length 11 means the null byte is there, and injection should work on an unpatched php. You haven't proven to us that the static code `include 'sample'.php';` would work, and so I think this question is bogus now.

Comment: So your problem is that a huge vulnerability in PHP is *not* working on your server? Let me drop everything and help you write this exploit code.

Comment: Sammitch : i was learning abt null byte injection after i stumbled upon this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIoXU-Ti8cs. if it is not working for me how am i going to learn how to prevent it?

Comment: Well you're learning the wrong lesson then. It's not 'look out for the null byte!' it's 'never ever ***ever*** trust user-supplied input'.

Comment: I retract my statment that this sounds bogus. It looks like they patched this whole thing in 5.3.4 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60985

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The null byte string vulnerability was [fixed](http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=305507) as of 5.3.4. That's why it's not working on your 5.3.8.

Comment: I want to point out that the `preg_` functions are still vulnerable to NUL byte attacks as of PHP 5.5.5. ;(

Comment: Not only `preg_` functions, the issue was not fixed with 5.3.4 for `include/require(|_once)` yet. If `magic_quotes_gpc` is on, null bytes should be escaped anyways, though.

Answer (score 1):

do you have `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled? The setting was saving everyones rearend because it escapes null bytes(the setting is removed since 5.4).

Comment: are you using real php? or some patched version like suhosin? post us the output of `base64_encode("$file.html");`

Comment: this is the output : c2FtcGxlLnBocAAuaHRtbA==

Comment: the null byte is definitely there, unescaped.

Comment: `php -r "echo base64_decode('c2FtcGxlLnBocAAuaHRtbA==');" | xxd` outputs `7361 6d70 6c65 2e70 6870 002e 6874 6d6c  sample.php..html` [note the 00 in the 6th group] so only the PHP error message is currently vulnerable to a poison null byte in OP's server.

Comment: Oh...I wasn't aware this got patched in 5.3.4

Comment: Sammitch : thanks for the answer..could you pls explain in simple terms what was the problem and what is an OP server?